Unable to connect to Dynamics in SSIS Project - Unsupported Browser error
I’m working in SSIS on a Windows Server 2022 Standard machine, Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.
I want to set up a connection to Dynamics 365 online using the Kingswaysoft Connector.
I enter the relevant information in the wizard. When I Test the connection, I'm prompted to enter my MFA info as expected. Once I've entered my MFA credentials I see a window titled 'Unsupported Browser' with the text 'Update your browser. Your browser is not supported or up to date. Try updating it or else download and install the latest version of Microsoft Edge.'Update your browser message
I have the latest version of Edge and Chrome installed. I have changed the Visual Studio Account authentication setting to 'System Web Browser' and tried setting the default browser to both Edge and Chrome.Sign In Options
I think that behind the scenes, Visual Studio is using Internet Explorer to authenticate. I've raised tickets with MS and Kingswaysoft, but no luck so far.

I've worked out that the issue was actually caused by me stupidly using the wrong credentials. Very misleading error in SSIS, but caused by user error on my part.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
